# control the time of splash screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a splash screen in my project. I have added the image in launch image it works fine. but I need to add a delay time for only 2 Sec and also I touch the splash screen it will go to home page.

Comment: Don't do it. It's not what the launch image is for, and it is annoying for users. If you're being asked to do this by a client, push back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create your own splash screen in terms of enhancing the duration for splash screen i.e. create controller with your splash image in it and dismiss it with timer or you can do like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    //Don't use this as its risky as per one of the comment
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4.0]; 
    // This will stop further execution and your splash screen would last for 4 extra seconds.

    splashScreen = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashView" bundle:nil]; 
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:splashScreen];
    [window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO]; 
}
```

Now in SplashViewController

```
-(IBAction)btnLoadScreenTapped:(id)sender{ //This is button touchup inside method we will load main interface from here
    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
}
```

**NOTE**

As per the one of the comment `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4.0];` use of this is risky so please don't use. Go for above code as you already did.

Comment: k bro. when i touch  the splash screen it should go to home page. how can i do that. send me any code for that.

Comment: splashScreen = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashView" bundle:nil];
    //_splashScreen is defined as:@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *splashScreen;
    
    [window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:splashScreen animated:NO];
    
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
what code write in the hidesplash method..

Comment: If you sleep during didFinishLaunching you risk being killed by the watchdog. This is not a good idea.

Comment: @jrturton I know that and that's why I have given the alternate solution as well. Anyway enjoyig upvotes and downvotes events, eventually :). Updated answer accordingly.